# Is this bulge in my ceiling due to a roof leak?

Tags: drywall, ceiling

If the roof had a unknown leak would I notice it, and how? Would it cause damage to the ceiling, and would I easily see water dripping?

My concern is this bulge in my ceiling:

[image]

Comment: I’m mainly asking if I’d notice a ceiling leak

Comment: I've added an image that the OP pasted a link to in a comment on an answer. I _think_ that, in his round about way, he's asking if this bulge is anything to be concerned about. I agree that the original wording of the question is very unclear and obtuse, and I invite the OP to [edit] his question to clarify what it is that he's asking about, since asking if he'd "notice drips on his iPad" is very subjective, confusing, and collecting close votes.

Comment: I don’t see the need for a close vote with the bad texture match and a specific square with no water dripping or discoloration,  I would bet it is a bad patch as Freeman has answered.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the picture that was posted in a comment (then added to the original question). It looks like this was a poorly done patch.

At some point in the past, someone had to remove a portion of the ceiling drywall. Possibly to repair a leaking pipe, to repair a water leak from outside, or some other reason. When the person (a lazy contractor, or a previous home owner) went to replace the drywall on the ceiling, he either:

1. didn't have the correct thickness of drywall to match what was already on the ceiling so installed a thicker piece that he had on hand
2. didn't attach the correct thickness of drywall well enough, and one end has begun to sag

This just looks like a poor repair job, not a current leaking spot. However, it's possible that if there was a leak here before, that the spot (whether plumbing above, or something coming in from outside) is leaking again, and it bears keeping an eye on it.

Whether one would "notice drops on an iPad" seems to be quite irrelevant to the question. Look for additional signs of water damage - additional sagging, damp to the touch and/or discoloration.

Answer (score 0):

A dripping ceiling leak is an extremely severe issue.

Water tends to stick to surfaces, unless there is so much water that it drips down.

If there is a huge leak, it would have been obvious; puddle of water or even flooding.

If it is something that can evaporate without a trace, then it's not going to drip. It is still a problem though.

Comment: But would I notice it if it is not to the point of dripping?

Comment: Are you looking for it? Depending on what kind of paint, it can range from seeping through and peeling off your paint (cheap, non-water proof), to completely hidden and not show up (high quality, water proof, environment resistant).

Comment: I can give you a link to a picture of it. Here. 

https://imgur.com/a/sKSOSve

Comment: That a patch from a previously repaired ceiling.

Comment: Think if you stand on something safely and push up on patch should tell if there is any problem.  A solid feeling is good.  If it can be pushed up or feels mushy, then get your landlord to look at it.